# How to start atop audio in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I want to add audio to an application. I have added audio, but the problem is that the audio does not stop till the audio clip is over.

How do I make it stop?

Comment: Interesting. How did you find how to write code to play audio in J2ME without finding the documentation about how to stop the audio playback?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Player interface from javax.microedition.media package. You can just call stop method of it. Please see Manager class documentation from MIDP API document.

```
try {
     Player p = Manager.createPlayer("http://myhost/abc.wav");
     p.start();
     p.stop();
 } catch (MediaException pe) {
 } catch (IOException ioe) {
 }
```